# Syntax error near variable and range in VHDL

Tags: fpga, vhdl, error, vivado

I learnt Java last year and started to learn VHDL and implementation on BASYS3 this year. I am just trying to display numbers on the seven segment starting from 0 and each time a push button is pushed the number will increase. I am familiar with the input and output declarations but I was not able to declare my integer variable as follows in VHDL vivado;

```
architecture Behavioral of top_module is
begin
shared variable total_foul : integer range 0 to 5;
total_foul := 0;
```

It keeps saying that there is a syntax error near variable and range which I couldn't find out. Also I tried to write the code for seven segment in case statements as follows;

```
 begin
        case total_foul is        
        when 1 => LED <= "1001111"; -- "1" 
        when 2 => LED <= "0010010"; -- "2" 
        when 3 => LED <= "0000110"; -- "3" 
        when 4 => LED <= "1001100"; -- "4" 
        when 5 => LED <= "0100100"; -- "5" 
        when others => LED <= "0000001"; -- "0"
```

But this also states that there is a syntax error near when.

The overall code for now is;

```
entity top_module is
    Port ( increase : in STD_LOGIC;
           decrease : in STD_LOGIC;
           foul : in STD_LOGIC;
           anode : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           LED : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0));

end top_module;

architecture Behavioral of top_module is
begin
anode <= "1111";
shared variable total_foul : integer range 0 to 5;
total_foul := 0;
begin
if foul = '1'  then
    if increase = '1' and decrease = '0' then
        total_foul := total_foul + 1;
    elsif decrease = '1' and increase = '0' then
        total_foul := total_foul - 1;
    end if;
    begin
        case total_foul is        
        when 1 => LED <= "1001111"; -- "1" 
        when 2 => LED <= "0010010"; -- "2" 
        when 3 => LED <= "0000110"; -- "3" 
        when 4 => LED <= "1001100"; -- "4" 
        when 5 => LED <= "0100100"; -- "5" 
        when others => LED <= "0000001"; -- "0"    

end Behavioral;
```

Thanks for everyone in advance.

Comment: make sure you're using VHDL93. Before, you couldn't declare shared variables in architectures. Also, the *verbatim* error text would possibly be helpful.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to have an `end case;` at the bottom of the case set? You also seem to be missing an `end if;` for the `if foul = '1' then` set. I'd also suggest indenting correctly (the case `when`'s should be indented from the `case`)

Comment: There are too many `begin`s and not enough `end`s. You really need to take another look at the basic syntax of the statements you're using.

Comment: Looks like you have no digital hardware design experience. Avoid shared variables for a start, learn signals instead. Useful search terms : clocked process, signal assignment semantics, delta cycles. And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954193/is-process-in-vhdl-reentrant/13956532#13956532

Comment: Shared variable is not a good design choice. And never code VHDL like C/C++/JAVA etc. It is very different as its a HDL not software language. You should start VHDL from basics

Answer (score 1):

Stripping out the parts of your code that are not problematic, we have:

```
architecture Behavioral of top_module is
begin
  shared variable total_foul : integer range 0 to 5;
  begin
  if foul = '1'  then
  begin
    case total_foul is        
      when 1 => LED <= "1001111"; -- "1" 
      when 2 => LED <= "0010010"; -- "2" 
      when 3 => LED <= "0000110"; -- "3" 
      when 4 => LED <= "1001100"; -- "4" 
      when 5 => LED <= "0100100"; -- "5" 
      when others => LED <= "0000001"; -- "0" 

end Behavioral;
```

The first issue is your shared variable. These can only be declared in a declarative region, in this case, it looks like you wanted it in the architecture declarative region, which is before the first `begin` in the code above.

The next problem is your second `begin` statement. What was this supposed to do? It looks more like you wanted to start a process here.

There is a 3rd `begin` after the `if foul = '1'` line. Again, what is this meant to do? It does not match any valid code pattern, so I suggest you just get rid of it.

Your case statement starts off OK, but where is the matching `end case;`?

Going back to the `if foul = '1'` line, it has no matching `end if;`.

---

You need to go back and look at some examples of simple VHDL architectures, then carefully write code with these in mind. Per a comment, you should also avoid using a shared variable until you really understand why you are using this, and not a `signal` or `variable`.